# InvalidOperationException occurs when I implement authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, invalidoperationexception

I tried to test a web page with authentication. The login page was fine, but after login, no matter authenticated successfully or not, an error with such message appeared:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Stack Trace:
[InvalidOperationException: Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.]

````
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.ShowCore(IWin32Window owner, String text, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, MessageBoxDefaultButton defaultButton, MessageBoxOptions options, Boolean showHelp) +1094
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox(Object Prompt, MsgBoxStyle Buttons, Object Title) +310
XXX.Login.LoginUser_Authenticate(Object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) in "a path that is not in the testing server"\Login.aspx.vb:56
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +144
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +107
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5028```
````

(Development and testing of the web page are done in different remote connections, but that path is actually in the development server.)

Even after I commented out the method `Protected Sub LoginUser_Authenticate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AuthenticateEventArgs)`, such exception still occurred, unless I take away `OnAuthenticate="LoginUser_Authenticate"` from `<asp:Login>`(another exception occurs though).

Anyone knows what's the reason of the occurrence of such exception? I have totally no idea about the content in the stack trace.

Comment: You're trying to show a WinForms MessageBox in a web application. That doesn't work. Do you want a JavaScript confirm? Or a more user-friendly modal?

Comment: That is actually not a part of my code. As I've said, I have totally no idea about the content in the stack trace.

Comment: You call `MsgBox` in your `LoginUser_Authenticate()` method. If you've removed that code, the web server is perhaps using an old assembly.

Comment: The exception occurs even after I have commented out whole `LoginUser_Authenticate()` method...